# Getting album name of song via last.fm API

Tags: api, last.fm

I am trying to use ["Last.fm" APIs](https://www.last.fm/api/) to get some metadata given song name.

This is a sample result when I use [/track.search](https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.search) API. However, I am wondering how to get the album name of the song because to use [/album.search](https://www.last.fm/api/show/album.search) API I need album name.

I appreciate any help or hint. Thanks.

```
{
  "results": {
    "opensearch:Query": {
      "#text": "",
      "role": "request",
      "startPage": "1"
    },
    "opensearch:totalResults": "685711",
    "opensearch:startIndex": "0",
    "opensearch:itemsPerPage": "1",
    "trackmatches": {
      "track": [
        {
          "name": "Believer",
          "artist": "Imagine Dragons",
          "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Imagine+Dragons/_/Believer",
          "streamable": "FIXME",
          "listeners": "359856",
          "image": [
            {
              "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
              "size": "small"
            },
            {
              "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
              "size": "medium"
            },
            {
              "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
              "size": "large"
            },
            {
              "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
              "size": "extralarge"
            }
          ],
          "mbid": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "@attr": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Can you share some code which you have tried so far?

Comment: If you just want to know how accessing a nested piece of data in a Json, then I would suggest just trying out [this](https://jsonpath.com/) online tool and give it this path to acess album name `$.results.trackmatches.track[:1].name`. Use your Json response as input

Comment: Language is kind of irrelevant but I am using [this](https://github.com/inflatablefriends/lastfm) library which wraps the API.

Comment: Once you get yourself familiarize with how Json paths work then you would be much more comfortable using any language/framework to achieve your goals.

Comment: @nabster you are not understanding my question. I want to get album name from song name. I am not asking for code.

Comment: Your question is not worded properly. 
`I am wondering how to get the album name of the song `
This means either you are trying to figure out how to traverse down to the album `name` in your current response or you are asking a last.fm API specific question?

Comment: I am asking about last.fm API question.

Comment: Gotcha. Why can't you use [track.getInfo](https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getInfo)? Since you are getting `name` and `artist` from your search results, you can use those and extract `album.title` from the second endpoint. _(Very poor API documentation from last.fm. I wish they had not used album's main track as example since most artists always have a lead track with the same album name)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on **last.fm** API documentation (*as of 05/09/2020*), [/track.search](https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.search) response does not contain album information for each track listed in the search results response. You would need to extract `name` and `artist` information from your search results response and use [/track.getInfo](https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getInfo) endpoint to get album information. Album name is `album.title` in the response.

#### Example

I am searching for "*seven nation army*" using [/track.search](https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.search)

```
{
    "results": {
        "opensearch:Query": {
            "#text": "",
            "role": "request",
            "startPage": "1"
        },
        "opensearch:totalResults": "30560",
        "opensearch:startIndex": "0",
        "opensearch:itemsPerPage": "1",
        "trackmatches": {
            "track": [{
                "name": "Seven Nation Army",
                "artist": "The White Stripes",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/The+White+Stripes/_/Seven+Nation+Army",
                "streamable": "FIXME",
                "listeners": "1583146",
                "image": [{
                        "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
                        "size": "small"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
                        "size": "medium"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
                        "size": "large"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
                        "size": "extralarge"
                    }
                ],
                "mbid": "24cc8311-98fd-423a-bed1-97728f5eabc5"
            }]
        },
        "@attr": {}
    }
}
```

From this response I will extract:

`$.results.trackmatches.track[:1].name` -> *"Seven Nation Army"*
`$.results.trackmatches.track[:1].artist` -> *"The White Stripes"*

and use as input for [/track.getInfo](https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getInfo)

```
{
    "track": {
        "name": "Seven Nation Army",
        "mbid": "24cc8311-98fd-423a-bed1-97728f5eabc5",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/The+White+Stripes/_/Seven+Nation+Army",
        "duration": "231000",
        "streamable": {
            "#text": "0",
            "fulltrack": "0"
        },
        "listeners": "1583146",
        "playcount": "12806149",
        "artist": {
            "name": "The White Stripes",
            "mbid": "11ae9fbb-f3d7-4a47-936f-4c0a04d3b3b5",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/The+White+Stripes"
        },
        "album": {
            "artist": "The White Stripes",
            "title": "Elephant",
            "mbid": "bb29bd28-71e7-32d3-ab5f-c2d33b25434a",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/The+White+Stripes/Elephant",
            "image": [{
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/4834c1de5bae49f594bd2f2df1f16286.png",
                    "size": "small"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/4834c1de5bae49f594bd2f2df1f16286.png",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/4834c1de5bae49f594bd2f2df1f16286.png",
                    "size": "large"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/4834c1de5bae49f594bd2f2df1f16286.png",
                    "size": "extralarge"
                }
            ],
            "@attr": {
                "position": "1"
            }
        },
        "toptags": {
            "tag": [{
                    "name": "rock",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/rock"
                },
                {
                    "name": "alternative rock",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/alternative+rock"
                },
                {
                    "name": "alternative",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/alternative"
                },
                {
                    "name": "indie",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/indie"
                },
                {
                    "name": "indie rock",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/indie+rock"
                }
            ]
        },
        "wiki": {
            "published": "09 Aug 2008, 10:12",
            "summary": "\"Seven Nation Army\" is the first track on the album Elephant by American alternative rock band The White Stripes. It was released as a single in 2003, and is one of the best-known songs from the band. Seven Nation Army reached #1 on the Modern Rock Tracks for three weeks and won 2004's Grammy Award for Best Rock Song. The song is known for its underlying riff, which plays throughout most of the song. Although it sounds like a bass guitar (an instrument the group had famously never previously used) <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/The+White+Stripes/_/Seven+Nation+Army\">Read more on Last.fm</a>.",
            "content": "\"Seven Nation Army\" is the first track on the album Elephant by American alternative rock band The White Stripes. It was released as a single in 2003, and is one of the best-known songs from the band. Seven Nation Army reached #1 on the Modern Rock Tracks for three weeks and won 2004's Grammy Award for Best Rock Song. The song is known for its underlying riff, which plays throughout most of the song. Although it sounds like a bass guitar (an instrument the group had famously never previously used), the sound is actually created by running Jack White's semi-acoustic guitar (a 1950s style Kay Hollowbody) through a whammy pedal set down an octave. The riff was composed at a sound check before a show at the Corner Hotel in Melbourne, Australia, according to the set notes in the booklet which accompanied the Under Blackpool Lights DVD. The riff was inspired by the main theme of the Fifth Symphony composed by Anton Bruckner (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgXBp-oEIR0&feature=youtu.be&t=21m29s).\n\nThe song shows a rare example of the Phrygian Half Cadence in popular music. It is also a rare example of a popular song with a wholly instrumental refrain.\n\nAccording to White, \"Seven Nation Army\" was what he used to call the Salvation Army as a child.\n\nIn March 2005, Q magazine placed \"Seven Nation Army\" at number 8 in its list of the 100 Greatest Guitar Tracks. In September 2005, NME placed \"Seven Nation Army\" at number 5 in its list of the 50 Greatest Tracks Of The Decade. In May 2008, Rolling Stone placed this song at number 21 in its list of the 100 Greatest Guitar Songs of All Time. \n\nA remix of the song was used in the trailer for Battlefield 1, which caused the song to spike up to the low 100's on Itunes charts.  <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/The+White+Stripes/_/Seven+Nation+Army\">Read more on Last.fm</a>. User-contributed text is available under the Creative Commons By-SA License; additional terms may apply."
        }
    }
}
```

This gives us `$.track.album.title` -> *"Elephant"*

Now use that for [/album.search](https://www.last.fm/api/show/album.search) endpoint to get album information.

Comment: Thank you so much. You went above and beyond. Thanks

Comment: Your question _piqued my curiosity_ and I had to find it out for myself. Good luck with whatever you are building :)

Comment: I am working on this: https://github.com/amir734jj/stream-subscription-api Thanks again